# Do i need an ssd case of type m key?

Tags: ssd

I have a dell xps 15 9560.
Windows has crashed and I'm not able to boot.
I have some files I want to resque from the ssd.
I have removed the ssd and it has product nr cx2-8B512-Q11 like the one in this picture
https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=0D9-00AN-00001

Thinking this was an pci e M2 ssd I ordered this product
https://www.conrad.nl/p/icy-box-ib-183m2-m2-harde-schijf-behuizing-1768113

It does not fit together.

The product's packaging says it supports B-Key and B+M key.

My conclusion is that it does not fit together because the ssd from my dell is of type M key. Am I correct?

Or has it something to do with m.2 Sata vs m.2 pci e?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. Your linked [picture](https://c1.neweggimages.com/NeweggImage/ProductImageCompressAll1280/AD9Y_131657060806609899KP26TfYTPB.jpg) of the Dell M.2 has good resolution and you can see the little numbers at the connector. A 1 (top) and a 75 (bottom). The key notch is near to the 75 making this device a M key.
B key would be a notch near the 1.
B+M key would be both notches.

So your case supporting B+M has both notches meaning you could fit either a B key, a M key or a B+M key module.

Another measure why it couldn't fit is the module thickness.
Your dell module has 80mm x 22mm x 3.65mm dimensions and according to [the manufacturer site](https://www.raidsonic.de/products/external_cases/external_cases_m2_m_sata/index_en.php?we_objectID=4374#technical_data) of your case it supports 22x30/42/60/80 mm. They do not state thickness.

However physical dimension are only one part. You are also right with your last statement. Your dell ssd uses "Host Interface PCIe Gen 3x4" and your case is "M.2 SATA".

You need a case that states **"M.2 NVMe PCIe SSD"**.